# SQL: Return a column containing the number of rows with the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that is returning systems and areas from my database like so:

```
SELECT  Areas.ID AreaID,
    Areas.Name AreaName,
              Systems.*

FROM Systems
INNER JOIN Areas ON Areas.ID = Systems.AreaID
WHERE ....
```

THis returns data that looks like the following:

```
|  AreaID   |  AreaName   | SystemName  | ...
|     1     |    area1    |     sys1    |
|     1     |    area1    |     sys2    |
|     1     |    area1    |     sys3    |
|     1     |    area1    |     sys4    |
|     2     |    area2    |     sys5    |
|     2     |    area2    |     sys6    |
```

I would like to return an additonal column containing the number of systems in each area returned, so that I end up with something like this:

```
|  AreaID   |  AreaName   | SystemName  |  noOfSystems  | ...
|     1     |    area1    |     sys1    |       4       |
|     1     |    area1    |     sys2    |       4       |
|     1     |    area1    |     sys3    |       4       |
|     1     |    area1    |     sys4    |       4       |
|     2     |    area2    |     sys5    |       2       |
|     2     |    area2    |     sys6    |       2       |
```

I.E. There are 4 systems with the area id of 1 and 2 with the area id of 2.

How can this be done? I'm sure i've heard of a built in function that does this but I can't find quite what I want.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: @steinar I am not sure why you removed the sql server 2008 tag, it notes what database they are using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want use the aggregate function `COUNT()` and then `GROUP BY`. This can be done in a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  Areas.AreaID AreaID,
    Areas.areaname AreaName,
    s1.SystemName,
    (select count(systemname) 
     from systems s2
     where s1.areaid = s2.areaid
     group by areaid) noOfSystems
FROM Systems s1
INNER JOIN Areas 
    ON Areas.AreaID = s1.AreaID
WHERE ....
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d60e/13)

Or you can use a subquery that you join to get the total count:

```
SELECT  Areas.ID AreaID,
    Areas.Name AreaName,
    s1.SystemName,
    s2.NoOfSystems
FROM Systems s1
INNER JOIN Areas 
    ON Areas.ID = s1.AreaID
INNER JOIN
(
    select COUNT(SystemName) NoOfSystems,
        AreaID
    from systems
    group by AreaID
) s2
    on s1.AreaID= s2.AreaID
WHERE ....
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d60e/9)

This version uses a subquery to get the total count and then you join that back to the `Systems` table to return additional columns, if needed.

Or, you can use windowing functions if your RDBMS has this option by using [`Count() over()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  Areas.ID AreaID,
    Areas.Name AreaName,
    Systems.SystemName,
    COUNT(SystemName) over(partition by Areas.ID, Areas.AreaName) as NoOfSystems
FROM Systems
INNER JOIN Areas 
    ON Areas.ID = Systems.AreaID
WHERE ....
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d60e/10)

Comment: Windowing functions (count(...) over (...) ) also exist in other RDBMS, e.g. Oracle

Comment: Looking at the OP's desired output, I'm assuming they want a count of rows in the results with the same AreaID and AreaName as the current row, not the same SystemName.

Comment: @TimLehner fixed the first version and added demos of all three queries

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated subquery like this:

```
SELECT 
  a.ID AreaID,
  a.Name AreaName,
  s1.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(s2.SystemName)
   FROM Systems s2 
   WHERE a.id = s2.AreasID) AS noofSystem
FROM Systems s1
INNER JOIN Areas a ON a.ID = S1.AreaID
WHERE ....
```

**Or:**

```
SELECT  
    Areas.ID AreaID,
    Areas.Name AreaName,
    Systems.SystemName,
    COUNT(Systems.SystemName) AS noOfSystems  
FROM Systems
INNER JOIN Areas ON Areas.ID = Systems.AreaID
WHERE ...
GROUP BY 
    Areas.ID AreaID,
    Areas.Name AreaName,
    Systems.SystemName;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give us the count of rows in the results with the same AreaID and AreaName as the current row.  Since I'm not sure if AreaName is unique, I'm including it in getting that count:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    -- Original query
    SELECT Areas.ID AreaID,
        Areas.Name AreaName,
        Systems.SystemName
    FROM Systems
        INNER JOIN Areas ON Areas.ID = Systems.AreaID
    --WHERE...
)
SELECT AreaID,
    AreaName,
    SystemName
    -- Here's where we get the count of rows returned for each unique area
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte WHERE AreaID = c.AreaID AND AreaName = c.AreaName) AS noOfSystems
FROM cte c
```

Using a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) in this fashion will allow us to use the original query without the need to alter it.